How should a stranger act?
I came across the full list of Delphic maxims on Wikipedia -- the list starts with "Know thyself" -- and am intrigued by this one:

"If you are a stranger, act like one."

I've been a stranger all my life. And of course, I am aware of certain things that are expected of strangers: respect the local culture, apply the law of the land, criticise sparingly... I would add to that list: behave as who you are, don't try and become who you are not (a local). That is to say: rather than try to blend in, give to them locals the kind of exoticism and excentricity that they expect of you as a foreigner. I was slow to learn that one.
Is there anything else? Did I miss something? How should I act as a stranger?

The maxims don't come with a manual, so they are up to personal interpretation. But this site is about written philosophy, so there cannot be a correct answer, making this question off-topic, IMO.

Anything ever written is open to personal interpretation, no?

I am not really interested in "other pieces of writing from that time", which I doubt exist anyway. I am more after a philosophy of "strangyness", an ethic of travel.

there is this paper "The philosophy of manners: a study of the 'little virtues'", which seems to scrape together what can be found:

In demonstrating why manners are important to our mutual expectations, Johnson reveals a terrain which modern moral philosophy has left largely unmapped.


Why focus on "manners", tho? Ethics is about more than manners.

Because your question is only about manners. Awareness of being a stranger while acting is only about manners. Nobody asks the trolley problem with "but what if the person at the lever is a stranger?"

Maybe they should. One of ambiguities in the trolley problem is that it fails to define the responsibilities and other qualities of the person at the lever. If that person is part of the station's staff and knows how the levers work, she is then under some responsibility to act, but if that person is a total stranger to the manipulation of train levers, knows not how they work, and is not habilitated to pull levers, then her obligations are far less.

It has also to see with feeling empowered or legitimate to intervene. But the broader point is that the characteristics of the person at the lever are ethically significant.

@tkruse OK, so you think this particular Delphic maxim is about good manners... To be fair, it was carved in marble right next to another one saying "Don't put your finger up your nose".

The Commands of the Seven Wise Men is a collection of antiques dicta, but not necessarily all from inscriptions at the temple of Apollon in Delphi.
See Classical Bulletin 63 (1987). In the paper 'Records of "The Commandments of the Seven Wise Men" in the 3rd c. B.C. Classical Bulletin 63 Vol. 3 (1987)' lists the dictum on p.74 as no.12.
The grammatical form of the dictum

Ξένος ὢν ἴσθι

from the OP’s post is an imperative with the verbal form ἴσθι. It is the imperative of "oἶδα = I know". Hence the imperative means “be aware of”.
And the whole dictum says:

If your are stranger then be aware of being a stranger.

Possibly it is an admonition on prudence.

Thanks for the revised translation. Prudence is indeed important for strangers and travellers. To travel is to take risks.
